# jQuery UI tabs style fine - now how can I get them to work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps-api-3, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-gmap3

Hate to beg, but I'm stumped. On this [map website](http://tnfc.raganadvertising.ca/) I cannot get the UI tabs in the popup InfoWindow to switch between "film", "synopsis", and "location". Using jQuery gmap V3, latest versions of jQuery and jQuery UI. Creating UI tabs in the gmap InfoWindow on addMarker function:

```
$('#map').gmap('addMarker', markers[i]).click(function() {
    var title = $j(this).attr('title');
    $('.tabs').tabs({
        create: function(e, ui){
            console.log('here');
        },
        show: function(e, ui){
            console.log('showing'); 
        },
        select: function(e, ui){
            console.log('WHY U NO WORK');
        }
    }); // init tabs
    $('#map').gmap('openInfoWindow', {'content': $('#'+title).children('.content').html() }, this);
});
```

Tabs created in the info window get styled properly but will NOT switch. I've tried the tabs "left fix" thing:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide {
    position: absolute !important;
    left: -10000px !important;
    display:block !important;
}
```

... to no avail. I've got a super simple test set up [over here](http://tnfc.raganadvertising.ca/test/) (taken from this [short tutorial](http://programmingshare-thienle.blogspot.ca/2011/11/multitab-infowidow-in-google-map-v3.html)), and it works great. Where can I start debugging? Any suggestions as to what might be wrong? FTP cred available on request! HUGE thank you in advance...

Quick links:[jQuery gMap plugin](http://tnfc.raganadvertising.ca/wp-content/themes/toolbox/js/jquery.gmap.min.js?ver=2.1.2) | 
[marker plotting js](http://tnfc.raganadvertising.ca/wp-content/plugins/tnfc-gmap/js/tnfc.js) | 
[theme js](http://tnfc.raganadvertising.ca/wp-content/themes/toolbox/js/tnfc_theme.js?ver=1.0) |

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The tabs are switching perfectly for me? I am a bit confused to what your question is.

Comment: Clarified in question - can't get InfoWindow tabs to switch between the 3 tabs at http://tnfc.raganadvertising.ca/. That site works for you?!

Comment: Works for me in Chrome (I see tabs at the bottom of the page), are there supposed to be tabs in the infoWindows?  I get a javascript error in IE: 'console' is undefined.

Comment: problem tabs are in infowindow, not the ones at page bottom :)